# WMI script to list of memberships of current computer?

Tags: wmi, vbscript

I have a AD hosted on 2003R2 and 2008R2, I would like to check the membership for the domain computer (e.g. compA) when an user logs on using that computer (e.g. compA) and perform certain operations inside a script. I think WMI could probably be useful but I am unable to find the proper query to get the list of groups of the computer account in question. Any idea?

Comment: Memberships of what?

Comment: I mean memberships of the computer, sorry forget to mention that there is an Active Directory already installed and the computers are all joined to that domain.

Answer (score 1):

Get-WmiObject win32_ComputerSystem | Format-List DomainRole

```
        0"Stand Alone Workstation"
        1"Member Workstation"
        2"Stand Alone Server"
        3"Member Server"
        4"Back-up Domain Controller"
        5"Primary Domain Controller"
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I do not need the roles for that machine and instead I want to get a list of groups (domain local group) associated with that machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that I've modified from [this site](http://www.winfrastructure.net/article.aspx?BlogEntry=Get-users-groups-using-VBScript). I haven't tested the code, but it looks sound.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, strDomain, strComputer, objComputer, objGroup, strGroupMemberships
Dim arrGroupMemberships

' Get the domain and username from the WScript.Network object
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strDomain = objNetwork.UserDomain
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName

' Instanciate the user object from the data above
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strDomain & "/" & strComputer)

' Run through the users groups and put them in the string
For Each objGroup In objComputer.Groups
    strGroupMemberships = strGroupMemberships & objGroup.Name & ","
Next

arrGroupMemberships = Split(strGroupMemberships, ",")

' Loop through array to get groups that this computer is a member of
```

This should get you going in the right direction if you haven't solved it by now.